# Enable Authentication on strimzi kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl, strimzi

i'm tyring to enable authentication on strimzi kafka. below is my yml

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.2.1
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
          usernameSecretRef:
            name: kafka-user-auth
            key: kafka-user
          passwordSecretRef:
            name: kafka-user-auth
            key: kafka-pass
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.4
      limits:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.5
    template:
      pod:
        tolerations:
          - key: kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority
            operator: Equal
            value: spot
            effect: NoSchedule
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: '3.1'
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 10Gi
      deleteClaim: true
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: kafka-metrics-config.yml
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 2Gi
      deleteClaim: true
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: zookeeper-metrics-config.yml
  kafkaExporter:
    topicRegex: .*
    groupRegex: .*
```

but when applying this yml, i get below error
`error: error validating "strimzi-kafka-with-auth.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Kafka.spec.kafka.listeners[1].authentication): unknown field "passwordSecretRef" in io.strimzi.kafka.v1beta2.Kafka.spec.kafka.listeners.authentication, ValidationError(Kafka.spec.kafka.listeners[1].authentication): unknown field "usernameSecretRef" in io.strimzi.kafka.v1beta2.Kafka.spec.kafka.listeners.authentication]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

i tried different approaches, e.g.

```
authentication:
      type: scram-sha-512
      username: myuser
      passwordSecret:
        secretName: myuser-secret
        passwordKey: password
```

and this

```
authentication:
  type: sasl_plaintext
  usernameSecret:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: myuser-secret
      key: myuser-username
  passwordSecret:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: myuser-secret
      key: myuser-password
```

and this

```
authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
          username: my-kafka-user
          password: my-kafka-password
```

but none of the above approaches seem to work, i get errors like it's not recognizing either `username` or `password` fields or not recognizing `usernameSecret` and `passwordSecret` fields

**UPDATE**

i am now creating kafka using below yml which works fine

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.2.1
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.4
      limits:
        memory: 1Gi
        cpu: 0.5
    template:
      pod:
        tolerations:
          - key: "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"
            operator: "Equal"
            value: "spot"
            effect: "NoSchedule"
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: kafka-metrics-config.yml
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: zookeeper-metrics-config.yml
  kafkaExporter:
    topicRegex: ".*"
    groupRegex: ".*"
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

and a user using user operator

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: my-user
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  authentication:
    type: scram-sha-512
```

now when i try to connect kafka client, it requires ssl certificates. however i want kafka broker to authenticate the client using username/pass and transport data over tls without certificate verification. is it possible? i don't want any certificates to be placed on client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Kafka` custom resource does not configure any passwords or users. It only configures the authentication type. The actual users and their credentials are separate from that. You can create users for example using the `KafkaUser` resources through the User operator. Or you can do it directly in Kafka using Kafka Admin APIs if you don't want to use the User Operator. Or with some authentication methods such as OAuth, the users live somewhere else completel.

You can check out the examples: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/tree/main/examples/security and / or read the docs which have some examples as well (e.g. https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#assembly-securing-kafka-str). You can also check the [API reference](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/configuring.html#api_reference-str) which shows which fields actually exist and can be used.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Jakub, sure let me try this approach

Comment: i have tried above approach, i created a kafka resource and a kafka user using user operator. it all works fine and i have username and password, only problem is that when connecting to kafka using client, it requires certificates, however i don't want to use certificate verification. all i want is my kafka client to connect with broker using user/pass and transport data over tls without certficates verification on either side

Comment: please check update on my question

Comment: That depends on whether you enabled TLS or not.